# Storing properties of object with array

Tags: javascript

I have an array which I want to use to store properties in.

For example:

```
player[0].name = bla1;
player[0].money = 130;
```

Now I created the for loop, but when I try to store the name in it, I get an error.

```
   var player = [];
   for(i=0; i < players; i++)
   {
     var x = i + 1;
     var nickName = document.getElementById('player' + x + 'name').value
     player[i].name = nickName;
     console.log(player[i].name);
   }
```

I got the error when I tried to add the property:

```
 player[i].name = nickName;
 console.log(player[i].name)
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the object before you can put properties on it:

```
var player = [];
for(i=0; i < players; i++)
{
    var x = i + 1;
    var nickName = document.getElementById('player' + x + 'name').value
    player[i] = {};                   // *** Create the object
    player[i].name = nickName;
    console.log(player[i].name);
}
```

And while you're at it, you can add the property while creating:

```
var player = [];
for(i=0; i < players; i++)
{
    var x = i + 1;
    var nickName = document.getElementById('player' + x + 'name').value
    player[i] = {
        name: nickName
    };
    console.log(player[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Gonna accept this answer in 10 minutes (after the timer). Kinda trying to figure out how objects work, thanks a lot!

Comment: @C.Ronaldo: Note epascarello's thing about `length`, which I have to admit I read right past in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

First there is no length, so I am not sure exactly what you are looping over

```
for(i=0; i < players; i++)  <--
```

And if the index is undefined, you would need to add an object into the empty index.

```
player[i] = player[i] || {};  //If there is no player defined, add an object
player[i].name = nickName;
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So did I until I looked at it again and did the Ninja edit. lol

Comment: Oh sorry, it's from another piece of code, should I leave it like this or should I edit it in? Thanks for explanation about players[i] || {}; btw ;)

Comment: @C.Ronaldo It should be `i < players.length` if that is what you are asking. Personally I would use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

You should set player[i] as an object first.
So it will be :

```
 var player = [];
 for(i=0; i < players; i++)
 {
   var x = i + 1;

   var nickName = document.getElementById('player' + x + 'name').value
   player[i] = player[i] || {};
   player[i].name = nickName;
   console.log(player[i].name);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you explain what players[i] || {} does? Never seen it before.

Comment: JavaScript || operator is logical OR. So it will return first passed value which is true. It means if players[i] exist use it if not declare new object;